# would mysql cluster help my situation?

Tags: mysql, logging, cluster-computing, analysis

I am dealing with several gigabytes of WAF logs.

What I mainly do is searching for some pattern using

"select * from tbl where condition1 and condition 2 and so on"

The problem is the columns are not indexed.

It takes 5~10 minutes to just one simple select query with some conditions.

I am thinking about adopting mysql cluster for better performance and stability.

Would it help my situation? or is there any better way to do it?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The problem is a lack of appropriate indexes ("the columns are not indexed"). So the proposed solution is to implement MySQL Cluster with NDB in memory storage engine. *What?* It seems like we're skipping over the idea of giving adequate memory to the InnoDB buffer pool and adding appropriate indexes. But knock yourself out. Why not go for a Teradata cluster or Hadoop?

Comment: @ spencer7593 Thank you for the quick reply. about the indexing part, due to the nature of the data (columns of very long strings and I often use query "like '%something%' ),I think,  indexing is not a good idea. I will try what you suggested anyways. Thanks :-)

Comment: So, the problem isn't just "the columns are not indexed".  The problem is that the queries can't make effective use of indexes.